# Count a cell based on if a cell in the same row has a checked checkbox

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I want to write a formula to count the Total Cost cell in column F, only if the cell in H is checked. I've approached it a few ways, but the Countifs formula isn't computing it.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 0):

Try `filter()`, like this:

`=sum( iferror( filter(F2:F, H2:H) ) )`

The formula assumes that the data table spans the range `A1:H`.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)